# Google Analytics query performance & historical data

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

We are pulling google analytics data into BigQuery and will be serving it up through queries to our members (120,000 individual members) when they view their dashboard on our member intranet. When performing a test query across four tables (4 days of data) we have, it took 11.5 secs,   Our reports will query up to 90 days of data - so that would be 90 different tables and so the response time needs to be much better. What settings do we change so that the access times vastly improve from these initial tests?

Also, when we first connected to our GA profile, we should be seeing historical data but all we see are the days since the connection was made 4 days ago. What settings can we change so we see the past 4 months of data that exists?

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are a Google Analytics Premium customer, as you are able to get Google Analytics data sent straight into BigQuery.

StackOverflow isn't a very good place to ask design or architectural questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the good news is that as a Google Analytics Premium customer you have access to email and phone support - specially for questions like "What settings can we change so we see the past 4 months of data that exists?" (https://support.google.com/analytics/contactflow) - and for deeper discussions there's even a special mailing list for BigQuery+Analytics Premium users.

Now, for questions like "how can I improve this query performance", you really need to provide a query and/or more context so people here can help you effectively.